# Spring security 404 error redirect(ResourceNotFoundException)

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, web.xml

I have added an entry in my *web.xml* to redirect to an custom error page in case if the user is hitting a invalid URL. Basically it is a custom error page which shows not a valid resource. The problem I am facing is when it redirects, it is not holding the session, so it always gets redirected to the login page.

I tried adding security none for this page but still it is not working. Do you know why the session become `null` when it directs for a `ResourceNotFound` exception (404). If I directly hit the error page by typing the URL in browser it is working fine.

web.xml configuration.

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/ResourceNotFound</location>
 </error-page>
```

if I hit my local

*local:8080/myapp/ResourceNotFound* it will load the page, but if I hit an invalid URL the redirection from dispatcher will have invalid session and redirecting to login page. I just want to understand why the session is becoming `null` in case of redirect?

Comment: please spring security version,redirection code

Comment: Spring security may detects that the URL is not accessible before spring-mvc tries to load it. That could explain this behaviour. Try to load a spring-security allowed non existent page to confirm.

Comment: We're hitting a similar error to this now.  I realize this is three years old, but did you ever find a viable solution?